# INSERT new rows into a table by copying existing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

There are a few questions that refer to inserting a new row by copying an existing row.

This question builds on it, but is substantially different.

I have a table with 9000+ rows. There are about 10 columns. Column 1 is an auto-increment which is the unique key.

I would like to insert into the table exactly the same number of rows as exist by copying everything from existing rows, except obviously Column 1, but also except Column 10 which will change based on value of column 10 in existing row, e.g. if col 10 is 23 in existing row it becomes 52, if col 10 is 25 in existing row it becomes 53.

So basically the only difference between existing rows and new rows would be col 10 value (apart from unique ID). And col 10 will take a very limited number of values.

Would something like this work?

```
INSERT INTO mycooltable (col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) 
SELECT col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, 52
FROM mycooltable WHERE col10 = 23

INSERT INTO mycooltable (col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) 
SELECT col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, 53
FROM mycooltable WHERE col10 = 25
```

Comment: Yes, something like that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would definitely work.

Note the third example of the `INSERT` syntax found here:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

**Reference**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO mycooltable (col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) 
SELECT col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9
,NewCol10= Case
`When Col10=23 then 52
`When Col10=25 then 53
`Else 55 --some default 
End                                                      
FROM mycooltable
```

The above script would also work